# Why would HttpErrors in web.config working differently in Azure to on-premise for URLs containing "%25f2"?

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have a react website hosted as an Azure app service. In the website I have a web.config file that includes httpErrors for providing custom error pages.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Error.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

This mostly works as expected in Azure, if I navigate to a path that doesn't exist I get the custom error page. However, when I try to navigate to a path that contains "%25f2" like "/..%25f2.../a" then it doesn't show the custom error page and instead shows the standard Azure 404 error page.

To test this I setup a local website on my computer in IIS and used the same web.config configuration. When I try "/..%25f2.../a" on the local IIS site it does redirect to the custom error page.

Why do these have different behavior and how do I make Azure redirect to the custom error page for this type of URL?

Answer (score 0):

After testing, it works for me.

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" errorMode="Custom" >
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/Home/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    <remove statusCode="500" />
    <error statusCode="500" path="/Home/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

[image]
[image]